# Guake configuration file

Tags: terminal, automation

I would like to **copy guake terminal settings** from one machine to another (like it use to be with dotfiles), instead of modifying settings in guake settings gui. However, I can't find where are guake terminal settings stored. I tried to search in guake documentation but there is no mention about such configuration file.
**Do you know, if it is possible?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `--save-preferences` option for this:

```
guake --save-preferences=myprefs.cfg
```

It will write a config file in the current working directory.

To load your saved prefs:

```
guake --restore-preferences=myprefs.cfg
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed!

Comment: Unfortunately, I am so low-reputated that I can not even mark my own question as answered O_o